# No Style/css On Django Admin

Tags: django, apache, django-admin

I'm a complete newbie to apache, so the the whole deployment process has been a pain in the backside, so bear with me.

I'm having the problem of my admin site using the css formatting, it's just coming up as plain html.

I know there are other questions that answer this issue here and elsewhere, but for the life of me I can't figure out to get it working. So if anyone can spot what I'm messing up I'd be eternally grateful.

The relevant lines in settings.py are:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/logparseradmin/logparser/static'

STATIC_URL = 'http://theyard/logparseradmin/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/var/www/Django-1.3.1/django/contrib/admin/media/'
```

and I have:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/Django-1.3.1/django/contrib/admin/media/
```

in my httpd.conf.

I've tried a whole bunch of variations on this, as the various answers on the Internet have suggested, but no luck.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's at least three things wrong here.

Firstly, your STATIC_URL is not probably a valid URL - `http://theyard/` is not a real domain name, and won't work unless you've got local DNS resolution (which, given your self-described newbie status, seems unlikely.)

Secondly, the path value of STATIC_URL doesn't match the `Alias` you've put in httpd.conf - STATIC_URL has `/logparseradmin/static/`, whereas `Alias` just has `/static/`

Thirdly, `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` should be a URL path, not a file path.

And without seeing the rest of your http.conf it's impossible to be sure, but there may be  fourth issue with mod_wsgi matching the URL before your Alias is processed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, I'll make some adjustments and return with the results. I'll just say though that while I may be a newbie, I'm doing this in a well established environment with a local dns, so theyard is infact a real name.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much, Daniel. A succinct explanation and which fixed the issue immediately.

Comment: The Alias directive always takes precedence over WSGIScriptAlias no matter the order.